# Associative array: how to get the key of the current element which is an array

Tags: php

I have an array

```
Array ( 
      [0] => Array ( [2006] => Array ( [0] => 12 ) )
      [1] => Array ( [2004] => Array ( [0] => 12 [1] => 6 ) )
)
```

How do I get the year so I can generate the folllowing using unordered list

```
2006
    December
2004
    December
    June
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php might help you

Comment: Why is your data organized in this way?

Comment: Try putting data in a database.

Comment: @thejh or XML, or something other than three levels deep nested associative arrays...

Comment: hmm what's wrong with it. I'm trying to create an archive of articles. It's basically an archive of old news articles. That is from a database but it's just been transformed into an multi dimensional array. It's going to be source data for tree UI element hence the unordered list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
$arr = Array(
  0 => Array(
    2006 => Array(
      0 => 12
    )
  ),
  1 => Array(
    2004 => Array(
      0 => 12,
      1 => 6
    )
  )
) ;

echo "<ul>\n";
foreach ($arr as $elem) {
  foreach ($elem as $year => $months) {
    echo "<li>$year\n<ul>\n";
    foreach ($months as $num => $month) {
        echo strftime("<li>%B</li>\n", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month));
    }
    echo "</ul>\n</li>\n";
  }
}
echo "</ul>\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's your unordered list:

```
foreach ($array as $year => $months)
    {
        printf('%04d: <ul>', $year);

        foreach ($months as $m)
            {
                $tm = mktime(0,0,0,$m - 1,1);
                print strftime('<li>%B</li>', $tm);
            }

        print '</ul>';
    }
```

Assuming the months stored are 1 for January and 12 for December. Hence the `$m - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure that you can use

```
foreach($key, $value in $array) {
}
```

Or something fairly similar. It's been a while since I've used PHP.

Comment: foreach($array as $key => $value){

Comment: No, that's wrong. To loop through a simple associative array, it's `foreach($array as $key => $value){ }`. Python has spoiled you, my friend :D